# PHP Mail with Plesk - Not Sending/Receiving Any Emails

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta, plesk, qmail

I recently got a new dedicated private server from 1&1. It has the latest version of Plesk Panel (11.5.30). On all of my webpages hosted from the server, none of them can send emails. Whenever I test this from here http://championsfunding.com/contact-us, it says that it successfully sent the email but I receive no emails at all. Here's a test PHP mail script with more detailed information: http://championsfunding.com/mail_test.php. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 5/7/14:**

I skimmed through the mail log and found no problems except

> May 7 10:05:53 u17259487 qmail: 1399471553.284374 delivery 29:
>   deferral: ./Maildir:_No_such_file_or_directory/

I created the *Maildir* folder in the root folder and still no emails.

Here's the log
[maillog.txt](http://championsfunding.com/maillog.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to send to addresses at the domain championsfunding.com?  If so, you'll have to disable mail services for that domain in Plesk since your email is hosted by Google according to the MX DNS for that domain.

The problem is that with mail services enabled the server doesn't attempt to resolve MX records for the domain.  Instead, it tries to deliver the email locally which isn't what you're expecting.

Here is [Parallels KB Entry](http://kb.parallels.com/en/116927) that explains the cause and solution.

Comment: Did you check the Mail Queue for stuck messages?  Also, are you sure your mail.log path is valid and writable by the webserver user?

Comment: Mail Queue is empty and I changed mail.log source from `/~daniel/mail_logs` to `mail_logs`. The folder does have 777 permissions. Still no logs or emails.

Comment: I would recommend using an absolute path for the mail logs (ie. /home/daniel/mail_logs). Also, would you mind posting your sending snippet to pastein (without sensitive information).

Comment: The absolute path for my server is `/var/www/vhosts/propertyregistration.com/mail_logs` and not `/home/daniel/mail_logs`. Here is my pastebin http://pastebin.com/1Y6w7yD6

Comment: I just ran a test from a Plesk box and it went through fine.   You  built this test script right?  And you know you have to click the link at the top of the page to actually send an email?

Comment: Yes, the link should activate the mailer. I also tested this script on another 1&1 server and it worked as well. Strange it is not working on this server.

Comment: Maybe the server you're on has been blacklisted. Have you run the server against http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx or similar?

Comment: Yep, just tried mxtoolbox and the site passes all the tests. I'm pretty sure it's not blacklisted. I'm thinking it's a configuration problem in the settings somewhere.

Comment: Updated with the mail log.